# Making this popup using JqueryUiDialog instead Fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

i'm not able to make the popup with jquery uidialog instead fancybox.
Here is screenshot of my popup made with fancybox. But for my personal issues rather use jquery uidialog.

[image: Pop up screen]

How can i:

1. Replace X button with image as shown in screenshot (i have a pic of the close button)
2. Made X button in that position as shown in screenshot.

Here's my html code (is in an external file with htm extension).

```
<div class="box_principale_mail">
<div class="box_wrapper_mail">
    <div class="page1">
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <div class="box_etichetta_dati_mail"><span class="etichetta_mail">Destinatario:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box_input_dati_mail">
                <input readonly="readonly" class="textboxform" id="testoDestinatario" value="' + email + '" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <div class="box_etichetta_dati_mail"><span class="etichetta_mail">Nome:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box_input_dati_mail">
                <input class="textboxform" id="testoNome" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <div class="box_etichetta_dati_mail"><span class="etichetta_mail">Cognome:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box_input_dati_mail">
                <input class="textboxform" id="testoCognome" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <div class="box_etichetta_dati_mail"><span class="etichetta_mail">Città:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box_input_dati_mail">
                <div class="div_citta">
                    <input class="textboxform" id="testoCitta" type="text" placeholder="Città" />
                </div>
                <div class="div_prov">
                    <input class="textboxform" id="testoProvincia" maxlength="2" type="text" placeholder="Prov." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <div class="box_etichetta_dati_mail"><span class="etichetta_mail">Messaggio:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="box_input_dati_mail">
                <textarea class="textboxform" id="testoMessaggio"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <div class="box_etichetta_dati_mail">
                <div class="etichetta_mail" id="testoPrivacy" onclick="Flippa()">Privacy</div>
                <input id="checkPrivacy" type="checkbox" />
            </div>
            <div class="box_input_dati_mail">
                <input class="pulsanteInviaEmail" type="button" value="invia" onclick="InviaEmail(\'' + email + '\', \'Richiesta informazioni\')" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page2">
        <div class="etichetta_mail" id="titoloprivacy">Condizioni della Privacy</div>
        <div class="box_div_campo">
            <textarea id="testoContenutoPrivacy" class="boxrotondato"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="box_campo_div">
            <input class="pulsanteInviaEmail" type="button" value="Rifiuta" onclick="TogliSpuntaFlippa()" />
            <input class="pulsanteInviaEmail" type="button" value="Accetta" onclick="SpuntaEFlippa()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For background and text css ok i can do it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you supply working snippet or bin?

Comment: if it is possible i asked only how to put on right side out button image instead default close of jquery dialog.... sorry but
easier than that I can not do

Comment: I asked you for this because your html doesn't looks like jquery-ui dialog. Do you want that I will show you how to replace it in sample jquery-ui dialog?

Comment: ok the html code shown is an external htm file that i load with jquery dialog ok? I wanna find a css trick to put every time i call jquery dialog the button outside jquery dialog and removing header (i know how to do it last) thanks!!

Comment: Use this example and show me how to put on the edge right corner the x with your personal of x image....http://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/24/

Comment: I just answer you. Let me know if it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do few changes in the css to override the default styles from jquery-ui.

The button is not in the right position it's just the way I can show you..

```css
.ui-dialog {
  overflow:visible !important;  
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqnsO.png) no-repeat center center !important;
  width:31px !important;
  height:29px !important;
  border:0 !important;
  margin: -40px -25px 0 0 !important;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close .ui-icon {
  background:none !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note** I overrided the `overflow:hidden` of the `.ui-dialog` so the close button could display outside the dialog but keep attention that it's not mess something else.

Comment: The problem was with the image and a little change in the css. Now it's looking OK, isn't?

Comment: What is `second step`? Your question include only one step.Why do you need `top:-5px`?

Comment: Ehm i asked for position on top right in the edge of close button image....... do you understand now? I wrote "2) Made X button in that position as shown in screenshot.". :D

Comment: ohh, I didn't see it.. I was updated my answer BUT read the note please - it's important..